# how to select zip codes in specific area/range?

Tags: php, range, distance, area, zipcode

I have a customer that requires that a user can add his/her zip code, then an administrator can select users in specific area range

for example:

```
user - zip code
1    - 24533
2    - 56924
3    - 35993
4    - 13435
```

admin's zip code is 39824

He needs to select people in area range of 5 kilometers by zipcode.
How can this happen using php or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[php/mysql zip code proximity search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410529/php-mysql-zip-code-proximity-search)

But, personally, I like the zip code range and distance calculation solution for you.  If you had lat and long I would suggestion another but this seems to be similar to what you need.

http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-zip-code-range-and-distance-calculation.html

Comment: The 2nd link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple 
You just need the latitude and longitude of the zipcodes against which zipcode you want to get the zipcodes. If you not have longitude and latotude get it from google it is free. you can easily get latitude and longitude by zipcode.

For example you want to get the zipcodes round 100 mile of 'H8t'

i have a table of zipcodes having latitude and longitude info.

First i write a query to my table to get latitude and longitude

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Master_ZIPCodes WHERE ZIPcode ='H8T'
```

after getting latitude and longitude i write a query below to get all zipcodes in the range of 100 miles of 'H8T'

```
SELECT distinct zipcode, 
3963 * (ACOS((SIN(45.456700/57.2958) * SIN(latitude/57.2958)) + (COS(45.456700/57.2958) * COS(latitude/57.2958) * COS(longitude/57.2958 - -73.712000/57.2958)))) AS distance 
FROM Tbl_Master_ZIPCodes 
WHERE 3963 * (ACOS((SIN(45.456700/57.2958) * SIN(latitude/57.2958)) + (COS(45.456700/57.2958) * COS(latitude/57.2958) * COS(longitude/57.2958 - -73.712000/57.2958)))) <= 100 Order by Distance
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving address with the zip code, then you can query the [Google geocode Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get the geocode of these addresses.

Once you have these geocodes, calculating distance can be done using code sample from [this site](http://www.corecoding.com/php-geocode-calculator_c25.html)